# error 121 mysql with constraints

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to re define my database design adding some extra tables so There are no repeated names for example in my table Departaments and Jobs...

But I am getting the error 121 which has to do with foreign keys, can you explain why is this problem?

[I am doing this in sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfaff)

I am trying to do something like this but had no luck in sqlfiddle there is what i have working at the moment

```
 CREATE TABLE Employee(
          EmployeeID  INTEGER      NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
          Name        VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
          Sex         CHAR(1)      NOT NULL,
          Address     VARCHAR(80)  NOT NULL,
          Security    VARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL          
        );

        CREATE TABLE Departments  (
            DeptID   INTEGER     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            DeptName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
        );
```

If I uncomment the code I get
**Schema Creation Failed: Can't create table 'db_2_2bf4a.project-employee' (errno: 121):**

```
        CREATE TABLE `Dept-Employee`(
          EmployeeID   INTEGER NOT NULL,          
          DeptID       INTEGER NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT fk_DeptID     FOREIGN KEY (DeptID)  REFERENCES Departments(DeptID),
          CONSTRAINT fk_EmployeeID FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID)
        );

       CREATE TABLE `Dept-Manager`(
          EmployeeID   INTEGER NOT NULL,          
          DeptID       INTEGER NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT fk_DeptID     FOREIGN KEY (DeptID)  REFERENCES Departments(DeptID),
          CONSTRAINT fk_EmployeeID FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID)
        );

        CREATE TABLE Jobs (
            JobID            INTEGER      NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            JobName          VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
            JobSalary        DOUBLE(15,3) NOT NULL default '0.000', 
            JobSalaryperDay  DOUBLE(15,3) NOT NULL default '0.000', 
            DeptID           INTEGER      NOT NULL
        );

        CREATE TABLE `Jobs-Employee`(
          EmployeeID   INTEGER NOT NULL,
          JobID        INTEGER NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT fk_JobID      FOREIGN KEY (JobID)      REFERENCES Jobs(JobID),
          CONSTRAINT fk_EmployeeID FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID)
        );

        CREATE TABLE Project(
          ProjectID    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
          ProjectDesc   VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
          StartDate     DATE NOT NULL,
          EndDate       DATE NOT NULL, 
          DaysOfWork    INTEGER NOT NULL,
          NoEmployees   INTEGER NOT NULL,
          EstimatedCost DOUBLE(15,3) NOT NULL default '0.000', 
          RealCost      DOUBLE(15,3) NOT NULL default '0.000' 
        );


        CREATE TABLE `Project-Employee`(
          ProjectID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
          EmployeeID   INTEGER NOT NULL,
          Note         VARCHAR(200),
          DaysWork     INTEGER NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT fk_ProjectID  FOREIGN KEY (ProjectID)  REFERENCES Project(ProjectID),
          CONSTRAINT fk_EmployeeID FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID)
        );
```

So after I do not know if this queries would be correct

```
INSERT INTO `Departments` VALUES (1, 'Outsourcing');
    INSERT INTO `Departments` VALUES (2, 'Technician');
    INSERT INTO `Departments` VALUES (3, 'Administrative');

    INSERT INTO `Jobs` VALUES (1, 'welder'    ,500.550,16.7 ,2);
    INSERT INTO `Jobs` VALUES (2, 'turner'    ,500.100,16.67,2);
    INSERT INTO `Jobs` VALUES (3, 'assistant' ,650.100,21.67,2);
    INSERT INTO `Jobs` VALUES (4, 'supervisor',800.909,26.70,3);
    INSERT INTO `Jobs` VALUES (5, 'manager'   ,920.345,30.68,3);
    INSERT INTO `Jobs` VALUES (6, 'counter'   ,520.324,17.35,1);

    INSERT INTO `Dept-Employee` (10,1);
    INSERT INTO `Dept-Employee` (10,2);
    INSERT INTO `Dept-Employee` (10,3);
    INSERT INTO `Dept-Employee` (10,1);
    INSERT INTO `Dept-Employee` (10,3);

    INSERT INTO `Jobs-Employee` (10,3);
    INSERT INTO `Jobs-Employee` (10,3);
    INSERT INTO `Jobs-Employee` (10,4);
    INSERT INTO `Jobs-Employee` (10,6);
    INSERT INTO `Jobs-Employee` (10,5);

    INSERT INTO `Employee` VALUES (10, 'Joe',  'M', 'Anywhere', '927318344');
    INSERT INTO `Employee` VALUES (20, 'Moe',  'M', 'Anywhere', '827318322');
    INSERT INTO `Employee` VALUES (30, 'Jack', 'M', 'Anywhere', '927418343');
    INSERT INTO `Employee` VALUES (40, 'Marge','F', 'Evererre', '127347645');
    INSERT INTO `Employee` VALUES (50, 'Greg' ,'M', 'Portland', '134547633');


    INSERT INTO `Project` VALUES (1, 'The very first', '2008-7-04' , '2008-7-24' , 20, 5, 3000.50, 2500.00);
    INSERT INTO `Project` VALUES (2, 'Second one pro', '2008-8-01' , '2008-8-30' , 30, 5, 6000.40, 6100.40);


    INSERT INTO `Project-Employee` VALUES (1, 10, 'Worked all days'    , 20);
    INSERT INTO `Project-Employee` VALUES (1, 20, 'Worked just in defs', 11);
    INSERT INTO `Project-Employee` VALUES (1, 30, 'Worked just in defs', 17);
    INSERT INTO `Project-Employee` VALUES (1, 40, 'Contability '       , 8);
    INSERT INTO `Project-Employee` VALUES (1, 50, 'Managed the project', 8);
```

Comment: on what table you are trying to modify?

Comment: when I run CREATE TABLE `Dept-Manager`(  i got error  121, if I delete that code I would get error 121 in CREATE TABLE `Jobs-Employee`(   I do not know why

Comment: I updated the sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfaff

Comment: Most probably answer is duplication of constraint name even without checking your schema :). @JohnWoo is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because the `CONSTRAINT` name you have provided already exist. Try changing the constraint name.

for instance `fk_EmployeeID` on `Dept-Manager` *already existed* on `Dept-Employee`

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ac52)

Comment: Do you know How to insert into `Dept-Employee` I was trying INSERT INTO `Dept-Employee` (10,1); But get Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10,1)' at line 1:

Comment: you lack keyword **VALUES**. It should be INSERT INTO `Dept-Employee` VALUES (10,1);

Comment: I did it but getting this error Schema Creation Failed: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_2_53af6`.`dept-employee`, CONSTRAINT `fk_EmployeeID` FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeID`) REFERENCES `employee` (`EmployeeID`)):

Comment: What is your timing? I should avoid that. Lot of questions about mysql, i can answer, I fail to do because you are too quick and accurate. So when you are there mysql developers do not need my help at that time at all :D

Comment: @cMinor what query are you executing when that error was generated?

Comment: I was executing INSERT INTO `Dept-Employee` VALUES (10,1);  and got Schema Creation Failed: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_2_53af6`.`dept-employee`, CONSTRAINT `fk_EmployeeID` FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeID`) REFERENCES `employee` (`EmployeeID`)):

Comment: @Sami I'm active at night because I have work during day time..hehe `UTC +8`

Comment: Dear @cMinor. Break your relations (foreign keys) before schema modifications and add them at the end... You will find to make modifications easier

Comment: @cMinor because table `Dept-Employee` is dependent on table `Employee`. The values must exist first on employee table before you can add on `Dept-Employee`. [SEE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66505 "Click to redirect")